# In-app purchase apply server side code using C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, in-app-purchase, asp.net-core-webapi, in-app-subscription

we got the access  code but we getting error 404 when we get subscription acknowledgement in c# ASP.net core

{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: }
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.xyz.app/purchases/subscriptions/com.xyz.monthly/tokens/doembgbhliaiacnnlgjgodoo.AO-J1OzdRwTiO0x8b

how to take acknowledge our token by server
we using this method
POST [https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}:acknowledge](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D:acknowledge)